# C# UWP show messageDialog every given time

Tags: c#, time, uwp, message

I'm fairy new to UWP and i'm working on a little personal project, what I want to do essentially is to show a message dialog every given time, or execute a task every given time, is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to execute a task when the application is on the foreground you can use [DispatcherTimer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br244250) to do this. 
You can have a look at the examples and know more about them.

If you are trying to execute some tasks on the background (when your application is not running) you have to register a background task . [More info here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task)